# What is the origin of the slang term “book” meaning “leave” or “hurry”?

Tags: etymology, slang

This verb is used in expressions such as “I’ll see you later – gotta book now”.

*Dictionary.com* has:

> 1. Slang. b. to leave; depart: *I’m bored with this party, let’s book.*[¹](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/book)

Anybody know the origin of this slang term?

Comment: I think this was a high school word for me ... which would place it in the late 1970's.

Comment: Here is another perspective on the word. http://www-personal.umich.edu/~jlawler/words/book.htm

Comment: Interesting.. In Dutch we use a literal translation of that verb too (also more or less slang). Never known it existed in English as well.

Comment: What is the Dutch word?

Comment: 'boeken' (infinitive). Usually used in a context such as *let's book* which would in Dutch be *we boeken 'm* or *laten we 'm boeken*; we use it pretty much only when we mean " let's get out of here quickly"

Comment: Listen to Robert Johnson's Terraplane Blues. "I'm booked and I've got to go."

Comment: @poepje It's funny, in German _bücken_ means to bend down; to stoop, and I'm told that in Austria a hundred or so years ago it used to appear in greeting expressions (somewhat akin to _I bow to thee_) given both on meeting and leaving the person. There just might be something to all that.

Comment: @TaliaFord, that’s a different word altogether (the Dutch form is _buigen_), cognate with ‘bow’ in English. [Edit: I’m nonsensing. _Buigen_ is the Dutch cognate to German _biegen_, not _bücken_. They do come from the same root, though, which is different from the ‘book’ root—the same root as ‘beech’.]

Comment: @TaliaFord /Janus The Dutch translation for 'bücken' is 'bukken'. The similarity between that and 'boeken' is merely coincidental ;) (just like the similarity between 'buch-bücher' and 'bücken')

Comment: I'm amazed that there is such an expression… which might indicate nothing more than my own ignorance.

The closest my ears have come would be *bugger off*, as at http://www.dictionary.com/browse/bugger--off 

Personally, I don't find *booking in and out* of base or *booking departure* any more likely than that *booking a restaurant* might mean *eating*.

On the other hand a military origin from foreign service somewhere doesn’t seem unlikely.

Comment: Here's another reliable attestation from a 1975 publication. *A Dictionary of Adolescent Folk Speech in Oakland* (University fo California, 1975). https://books.google.com/books?id=SWNRAQAAMAAJ&q=%22let%27s+book%22&dq=%22let%27s+book%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjAgKW1t7HVAhWBbSYKHYJbC08Q6AEIQTAF

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Recent internet

This use of *book* is definitely earlier than the 1990s. Two posters on [*Ask MetaFilter*](http://ask.metafilter.com/80636/Etymology-of-the-word-book-meaning-go) date it to the 1960s:

> - “Booking it” has been slang for running away (from trouble or a tight situation) for as long as I remember. I am talking late ’60s Boston …
> - Thirding (or something) the not-a-Mass thing, it was in wide use in California in the 60s.

Some 10 remember it from the 1970s, and around 15 from 1980s.

From [*The Phrase Finder*](http://www.phrases.org.uk/bulletin_board/25/messages/833.html):

> A couple of references associate “book it” meaning to move fast with “book it” meaning to study or “hit the books”. (*Black Talk: Words and Phrases from the Hood to the Amen Corner* by Geneva Smitherman, Houghton Mifflin Co., Boston, 1994; and *Random House Historical Dictionary of American Slang*, Volume 1, A–G by J.E. Lighter, Random House, New York, 1994.) Random House says “book it” is influenced by “boogie”. Both sources say the phrase dates back to the 1970s. That’s when I first heard it.

### Dictionaries

The first citation in the *Historical Dictionary of American Slang* is from 1974:

> Time to book this joint.

[Another edition](https://groups.google.com/group/alt.usage.english/msg/010293407f7496fc?dmode=source) of the same book from 2002 or earlier links it to *boogie*:

> book …
>   3. [infl. by BOOG, BOOGIE, v.] to leave; to go fast; move along. – also 
>   constr. with “it”, “up”.

*[The Routledge Dictionary of Modern American Slang and Unconventional Langauge](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=5F-YNZRv-VMC&pg=PA108&lpg=PA108&dq=slang%20%22gotta%20book%22&source=bl&ots=miu1_E5JSm&sig=ji7myP5y2Tgz6lvtgF9HSJgvEgo&hl=en&sa=X&ei=wBi9T86cEJPS4QSazLw3&ved=0CGAQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=slang%20%22gotta%20book%22&f=false)* (2009) by Tom Dalzell and Eric Partridge agrees on US 1974:

> *2* to depart, usually hurriedly *US, 1974*
>
> - Belly sprang to her feet. “We gotta book – fast.” – Seth Morgan, *Homeboy*, p. 66, 1990
> - MARSELLUS: Whatch got? ENGLISH DAVE: He booked. — *Pulp Fiction*, 1994
> - We gotta book it if we’re going to make it to P.E. — *Clueless*, 1995
> - We gotta book. We’re catching a bus to Chi-town. — *Chasing Amy*, 1997

All the citations and reminiscences are from the US and mostly amongst schoolchildren. I’ve never heard it in the UK, where *scarper* might be used instead.

### alt.usage.english anecdotes

Over in *Usenet*’s [alt.usage.english](https://groups.google.com/group/alt.usage.english/browse_thread/thread/ee11c70084ceeb5/910bd4e726fcf625?q=%22gotta%20book%22&lnk=ol&#), there’s a 205 message discussion from 2002 on this (and in [1999](https://groups.google.com/group/alt.usage.english/browse_thread/thread/1b6d1765db99729f/6f0ee63a7f9831a8?q=booked%20group%3aalt.usage.english#)). Highlights include a poster (rzed) hearing it in 1968:

> I heard this usage no later than 1968 (from a co-worker in a job in left [*sic*] in that year), in the US Midwest. I don’t know the origin, although I’d think it is at least related to the use of *boogie* to mean “go”. It may be more common to say something like “let’s book it” than “let’s book”.

Another poster from the mid-west also remembers it from the late 1960s:

> I remember hearing the term in the late 1960s. I recall it as a slang term for “to leave”, as in: “Let’s book”. I don’t recall any connotation of running away, but there was a certain amount of alacrity associated with it.

And:

> We talked about this before (I looked it up – it was in 1999), and most of the people who knew the usage came from the Midwest. I know someone from Binghamton who says *book* meaning “move fast”, and when we discussed it in 1999, someone from Buffalo or Rochester also said they used it.

Another:

> In my experience, it was universal among U.S. servicemen in Europe in the late 1960s. It meant “to leave”. Period. After about 20 minutes in a bar, someone would yell “Book!” and 
>   all the cool people would proceed to the next bar.

And from the same poster in 1998:

> In the members of the US military of the 1960s, and its surviving human tatters today, “to book” does not mean “to hurry”, but rather “to leave the premises abruptly”. “Let’s book” means “Let’s get out of here”. At the end of an all-night party, some revelers had crashed (i.e. fallen asleep here and there on the premises), and others had booked (i.e., disappeared).

More from 1960s:

> This is exactly the usage I remember from the Calif. Bay Area in the 1960s – “he was bookin’ ” or “they were bookin’ right along”. No other forms of the verb. Now I’m wondering if “Let’s boogie” has any connection, because it meant sort of the same – Let’s get going. But I thought the sense there was “Let’s dance”. Was “bookin’ ” ever used to mean dancing?

Some suggested origins are:

- *booking out* of a hotel is to leave;
- from *boogie*, that also meant to move quickly, to get going;
- you could say of a fast moving car “it *booked*”, perhaps tied into breaking a speed record, which may be entered in a book;
- *booked*, as in “departed”, comes from the days of ocean liners – “*booked* passage”.

Answer (score 4):

I've heard it started as a military term from the Army. You had to sign in and out in a log book whenever you left the company area. Especially when you went on leave (vacation). Think I read that it started around the Vietnam war years. I used to use it as a kid in the 80s. Also servung in the Army so I know all about signing in and out in log books.

Answer (score 3):

I grew up in Philadelphia in the 1960s and never heard the expression until I entered the US Air Force in 1972. It was very common military speech. It meant that someone else had left - "He booked" - or that the speaker desired to leave - "Let's book." It also meant moving quickly, as in: "he was REALLY bookin' it."

With absolutely no proof of this, I always assumed it came from a classroom setting. Picture the bell ringing at the end of class, the students all slamming their books shut, and beating feet.

Comment: Mike, welcome to ELU.  Your answer seems to be based only on your personal knowledge and experience and would be improved if you could find some sources.  It would be interesting if someone could assess Poepje's earlier comment.  Thanks.

Comment: @MichaelOwenSartin As a source of facts to support an answer, we do welcome a person's own knowledge. I don't mean to say you're wrong: peer-reviewed online sources are the gold standard. But Mike's observation about the military context is a useful fact.

Answer (score 2):

We used *book* or *booking* meaning to leave hurriedly or to go fast at my middle-class suburban high school in the mid-eighties in Minnesota. We only used the term *boogie* ironically.

Answer (score 2):

I've used "book" since the mid 70's in Rochester NY so it pre dates that by how much don't know but bit was widely used all over during that time and since. Usually its used very simply as "I've gotta book" ... meaning I gotta go now or "He was really bookin'" used when something /someone is going faster than normal

Answer (score 2):

It is definitely of U.S. military origin, as several previous commenters have stated. You signed a log book upon leaving and returning when granted leave or a pass. To "book" used as a verb simply meant that you were leaving your base with permission. There was no connotation of a rapid exit. And, there is no connection whatsoever to the word "boogie."

Comment: Being "definite" is not quite enough, some supporting reference is needed to qualify this as an answer. In fact, that's what the purpose of this Q&A is, although opinions and ideas that contribute to knowledge may be posted as comments. Can you help?

Answer (score 2):

I just checked with my boss. It was a common phrase in his high school in Wyoming. He claims that he heard it no later than about 1965 (graduated in 1969). Where he lived had no particular military influence, though he does not rule out that origin.

Answer (score 2):

I know this saying from African-Americans in the mid-sixties. Back then marijuana was still measured in a coffee can lid; that would be a "lid of weed"(an ounce). It makes sense that "book it" it might have come from the military; blacks were certainly over-represented in Vietnam. I guess it could mean sign in/sign out. Shorthand: "book it." The phrase reminds of another African-American phrase: "get hat." Meaning get your hat and let's go. Came into white usage when Jefferson Airplane used that phrase in "White Rabbit." Another bit of language later taken up by whites was explained by, I think, Malcom X who noted how grown black men turned a symbol of weakness into one of nurturing, bonding and strength by greeting one another as "Baby!"

Comment: Hi Gail, welcome to EL&U. You put a lot of titbits into your post, but it's not actually an answer. Unlike usual forums, where you can post things that are tengentially related to the topic at hand, Stack Exchange answers are reserved for answering the question only. If you do have an answer, you might like to [edit] you post to make it clear.

Answer (score 2):

On page 93 of the book *[Marine Sniper: 93 Confirmed Kills](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=A4qOIz9LseIC&printsec=frontcover&dq=MARINE%20SNIPER:%2093%20CONFIRMED%20KILLS&hl=en&sa=X&ei=H5CzVOGgCOf-ygObyYCoBA&ved=0CCAQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=book&f=false)*, *book* is used in a paragraph with an asterisk.

The footnote reads:

> * Marine jargon meaning to go or to leave. Until early 1970s, Marines were required to sign out on liberty in the duty NCO's log book as they picked up their liberty cards. From that came the term "Book Out", which was shortened to "Book."

Answer (score 1):

Check out this website, maybe it helps:
http://ask.metafilter.com/80636/Etymology-of-the-word-book-meaning-go

> *book* vb American
>   to depart, leave. A fashionable term of the 1990s in black street usage and also heard among white adolescents. A variety of euphemisms (like its contemporaries *bail*, *bill*, *jam* and *jet*) for “run away” are essential to the argot of gang members and their playground imitators. The origin of this usage is not certain; it may derive from an earlier phrase “book it”, meaning that someone has to return home quickly in order to record a transaction.

Comment: It's interesting. One person there speculates that it may derive from "boogie" which is a verb "to dance to fast music". Certainly I can imagine it would be a natural shift of the progressive form of the verb from "he's really boogie-ing" to "he's really booking".

Comment: I'v been using it all my life and that is well before 1990.  ...  As for the how? Just a guess, but when I was in the Army, we had to sign out in a book when we took leave or had a pass so it could hav started in a like way.

Comment: I've been using it since the early 70s. The quoted passage is so out of touch it sounds like it was pulled from *redacted*.

Answer (score 0):

I began using this term in the State of Illinois, City of Chicago in 1973. Peers at school were using it and thus, I added it to my vocabulary. I believe the term comes from 'booking passage; to depart'. After reading here that the Dutch use it for the exact same circumstances, I am conviced 100% that it is the true origin.

Answer (score 0):

A slang book dates backs to the late 1960's and the early 1970's. I am from Baltimore, Maryland and I went to Greenspring Junior High. The kids there used them to bully and disparage the character of folks who they didn't like or whom they were simply jealous of. The idea was to get a black and white composition book and on the front you would write the name of the home-room class. Usually, the creator, or the lead bully, would then start a single page for each individual person that he/she wanted to "Jone" on. Sometimes, every student in the section had a page in the book. The book would get passed around from person to person. Sometimes (lots of times), there would be anonymous postings. It was much like the cyber bullying of today -sans the internet.

The slang book was notorious for creating fights, contention, and all out discord in many junior high schools and middle schools in the area where I grew up. By the time I entered High School, they were non-existent.

Loris Lisa-Marie Hyman-Walker

Answer (score 0):

First heard 'gotta book' , 'man, he was bookin' in basic training Ft. Dix N.J. April,1970. It was ubiquitous , used by nearly everyone and well established. My guess for origin would be U.S. military Viet Nam mid '60's.Signing of log and pass books seems to me kinda sketchy. Interesting Dutch analog.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the OED entry under *book* as a verb:

> b. N. Amer. To move quickly; (also) to leave, go away, esp. quickly
>   or abruptly. Frequently with down, out. J. E. Lighter Hist. Dict.
>   Amer. Slang (1994) I. 237/2 records an oral use from 1974.
>
> 1977   SkateBoarder Apr. 71   Blazing trails of animal grace and
>   aggression, Constantineau..ends his performance by booking it through
>   the snake run.
>
> 1978   J. Webb Fields of Fire 197   Bagger, you book on out o' here,
>   man. I gotta rap with a brother, hear?
>
> 1987   Dirt Wheels Mag. Aug. 46/2   When you're booking down a fast
>   mountain fire road, make sure you know what's round the next bend.
>
> 1996   J. Whedon Welcome to Hellmouth in Buffy the Vampire Slayer:
>   Script Bk. (2000) 1st Season I. 26   Buffy. Uh, look, I gotta book.
>   I'll see you guys later.
>
> 2000   Calgary (Alberta, Canada) Herald (Nexis) 25 Apr. b1   I've
>   never felt heat like that... We had to run..and try to get the doors
>   open, then book it out of there.
>
> 2001   D. Lehane Mystic River 249   She's running full-out, he's gotta
>   be charging after her like a raped ape. I mean, he's booking through
>   that park.

There's also a noun meaning of *book*, "to close the book on", as well as uses mentioned above with respect to "booking" a suspect in a criminal case or logging in or out (often military).  The Google NGram of "close the book on" goes back quite a ways.

Answer (score -2):

The phrase "booking it" likely comes from the Scandinavian sailing term "psalmbooking," which means sailing with the wind (also known as "running").

Comment: Why is it likely?

Comment: Is that your own guess based on similar sounding names, or is there scholarship to back it up?

Comment: I don't know about likely, but the sailing term does seem to check out. Basically your sails are like two wings or an open psalmbook, that way one isn't blocking the wind to the other. Used when sailing directly downwind. So it would fit as an origin for "booking it". Unfortunately however this is otherwise tenuous: there is no evidence I can find that the slang term has any nautical or Scandinavian influence. Here is a reference for the sailing term: https://www.flickr.com/photos/75797806@N00/6920508325