# "To book" used as "to run"

Tags: meaning, verbs

Is it correct to use the verb *to book* with the meaning of *to run*? I heard this usage in situations like:

> The dog ran out and I booked it after him.

or

> I was booking it down the hill.

I couldn't find any meaning similar to this in the [Merriam-Webster Dictionary](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/book) or others.

Comment: "To book" dates from at least the 1960s: http://english.stackexchange.com/a/54273/9001

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*[Book](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/book)* here is used informally as a verb meaning *hurry or move quickly*.

> He didn't watch the show because he had to **book it** to school.

Comment: It seems that I need to start using the Oxford Dictionaries more often!

Comment: It's dialectal American, and it's recent. It's most commonly used in the progressive: _He was really bookin there_.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, most often, I've heard it used in phrases like, "Make like a dog with a tail between its legs, and book!"

Answer (score 3):

[Urban dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=book%20it) has a good description of this usage.

It is slang, but it means to leave rapidly or run quickly.

Without proper proof, I believe the origin to be something akin to "enter the record books".  Or, per Urban Dictionary it may be related to leaving a party quickly to go and study (hit the books).

Comment: We have a question for the origin here: http://english.stackexchange.com/a/54273/9001

Answer (score 0):

I have always understood "book it!" to mean hurry-up.  A few language forum postings indicate "book it!" was used in the 60s, and oft-mentioned it was either regional or American slang but "book it!" is not exclusively American

Answer (score 0):

My pet theory is that it's a bilingual play on words from the French 'Livre', for book, pronounced [/livʁ/](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/livre).

So: "I've got to leave" becomes "I've got to livre" becomes, "I've got to book".

Or maybe I need to go outside for a bit...

Answer (score 0):

The slang expression to book for to run at high speed might be connected with German "ausbüxen", said of young boys who run away from their parents with nobody knowing for hours where the boy is.